# Removing decimal point in limit to function in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-limitto

I am getting data from a JSON file, which I'm binding on an HTML page by {{regular expression}}.

I want to display only the first 5 characters of the number (including the dot). For example, if the number is "123.4567", I want to display only "123.4", so I apply `{{ exp | limitTo: 5 }}`. But if the number is "1234.567", then that evaluates to "1234", which I don't want; I want only "1234".

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Create your own filter:

```
angular.filter('fiveDigits', function() {
    return function(num) {
        var str = ("" + parseFloat(num)).substring(0, 5);
        var lastChar = str[str.length - 1];
        return (lastChar === '.') ? str.substring(0, str.length - 1) : str;
    };
});
```

And use it like any other:

```
{{'1234.0' | fiveDigits}} // => 1234
{{'12345.0' | fiveDigits}} // => 12345
{{'123456.0' | fiveDigits}} // => 12345
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
{{exp|number:0}}
```

The number is filtering with 0 decimal point.

Comment: But now,I have 3 conditions:
1-.0<number<100,then show 2 precision digits after rounding,ex:-if num=1.2898 then show 1.29,if num is 93.968 then show 93.97.
2.100<number<1000 then show 1 precision digit after rounding,ex if number =998.989 then show 999.
3.if number>1000,then show as it is but without any decimal point after rounding.
eg if no is 98985.95 then show 98986.
Can i write this in a single filter,do i have to write 3 different conditions for this?

Answer (score 0):

Angular allows you to create your Own custom filters

```
<div ng-repeat="students as student">
 <div class="student-name">{{student.name}}</div>
 <div class="student-fee">{{student.fee|limitDigit }}</div>
</div>    


angular.filter('limitDigit', function() {
    return function(decimalNumber) {
        var str = ("" + parseFloat(decimalNumber)).substring(0, 5);
        return str;
    };
});
```

The above code is an example of custom filter

Answer (score 0):

Use of number filter which is provided by Angular JS will solve your problem and if you need more validations and check on the value then as recommended you can create your own custom filter with the help of $filter service of Angular JS.